# Internal error and statement error- I4GL

Tags: informix, 4gl

When I run the program (Informix 4GL SE) I am getting the following error. IS there anybody know the solution?

FORMS statement error number -6327.
Internal error in the run time library file Report.c(933):

Comment: Informix 4GL documentation states that this error is the result of something "unpredictable occurring" and that you should contact Informix Technical Support for further assistance.

Comment: As @j.w.r suggested, you should be contacting Informix Technical Support (at IBM).  You'll need to specify the version of I4GL you're using, and the platform you're using it on (you could mention that here, too).  I can't immediately find error -6327 in the source code, but I'll look again.  Is `Report.c` (or, more relevantly, `Report.4gl`) one of your source files?  If so, then looking for `-6327` in that file might help.  How precise is your transcription of the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Does this only happen with one form, or all of your forms?

I'm fishing deep into dark memory here, but I believe it's as simple as failure to set one of $TERM, $TERMINFO, or $TERMCAP as appropriate for your platform - if it's one of these, $TERM must be findable in the termcap or terminfo.

OR - it could be a defective setting in $DBCENTURY, $DBDATE, or something similar.

Yes, it seems silly that Report.c should be involved in this problem, but that's just the way it is.

I hope it's not too late to help, or have you already solved it? This might be a good thing for you to post what the problem was.